# Need to use PLSQL variable if select returns more than one record. No need of collection/Cursors.

Tags: sql, plsql

I need to use PLSQL variable to hold more than three values . I don't want collection or cursor. Below is the requirement, v_cnt needds to be 9 instead of '0'. PLease help on this.

```
declare 
v_column VARCHAR2(200);
v_cnt number :=0;
begin
  select (SELECT listagg(TABLE_NAME,',')within group(order by table_name) FROM ALL_TABLES where owner in 'SYS' AND  rownum<10 )
  into v_column 
  from dual;

  select count(*) into v_cnt from all_tables where table_name in(v_column);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('v_column=' || v_column||'  VC-nt : = '||v_cnt);
end;
```

v_column will have comma separated values. I need to pass it in in operator, but v_column whole values considered as single value. IS there any way to pass it as separate 9 values inside IN operator.

Comment: Is this example procedure representative of your actual problem? Because as things stand, I would suggest you simply combine the two queries like so: `select count(*) from all_tables where table_name in (select table_name from all_tables where ...);`. If not, there are lots of examples of the "varying inlist" type problems both here on Stack Overflow and via Google, which you can search for yourself. However, I would steer away from using a string inlist if there were other, less sql incjection prone solutions available!

Comment: Actually, in my original case, i need to use that variable in many statements to avoid repetitive child queries.

Comment: Ii'm not following you... a variable that stores multiple values is called a collection, so how is it you want a variable to store multiple values but you don't want a collection?

Answer (score 0):

Given you're going to be using the values returned by the first query in multiple sql statements (and assuming that they can't be combined somehow) I would create a [global temporary table (GTT)](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/temporary-tables), e.g.:

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE gtt_reuse_table_names (table_name varchar2(30))
ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;
```

and then reference that in the queries in your procedure, e.g.:

```
declare
  v_cnt integer;
begin
  insert into gtt_reuse_table_names (table_name)
  SELECT table_name
  FROM   ALL_TABLES where owner in 'SYS'
  AND    rownum<10;

  select count(*)
  into   v_cnt
  from   all_tables
  where  table_name in (gtt_reuse_table_names);

  ...
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer from various searches,

I used below statement,

```
 select count(*) into v_cnt from all_tables where ','||v_column||',' like '%,'||table_name||',%' ;
```

and it returns '9'.

Thank you.